Protect against sandwich attack
In a scenario where i want to perform a trade on a DEX using high slippage, and i can perform the trade via my own program and then use CPI to do the swap, what checks can i add to my program to make sure i wont get sandwiched?
I've seen a few developers add something to their programs to do this exact thing, but they're close source, so i'm wondering if there's some common method for this?
I was thinking of comparing pool state for unusual behavior (so in transaction i include pool state from before submitting the transaction, and within my program i fetch it again and compare against it) but im not sure if thats a good idea as i presume it would be hard to differentiate between major state change due to sandwich attack and popularity of the token.

Does this answer your question? Sandwich attacks on Solana. Is this a problem?
